# How to use HG(Mercurial) in command prompt?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

How can I open the hg in the command prompt in any directory?

I have tried setting classpath. But nothing works..

I need to use Hg like below picture wherever am in the directory.

[image]

Comment: You need to add path to hg to your PATH environment variable

Comment: Once you set you need to restart the system. Thank you guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have path to `C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\` in your `PATH` variable

Open Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Advanced Tab -> Environment Variables

Make sure that under `PATH` variable you have `C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\` included

Answer (score 1):

In TortoiseHg Workbench open the repository and start a terminal window with Ctrl-Shift-T.
[image]